# MongoDB -moving from localhost to cluster using URI

Tags: java, mongodb, api

I currently have a MongoDB based API that's running on a local version of the server, as is default.

I want to move this over so that the interaction is happening with my online server, for which i have a login and URI string.

Where to do I put this?

I'm using SpringBoot in STS if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You must have added server location somewhere in your code like this

`mongodb://localhost:27017`

Here, replace localhost with your server IP and port, that's it!